# DateTime "null" / uninitialized value?

Tags: c#, datetime, null, initialization

How do you deal with a DateTime that should be able to contain an uninitialized value (equivalent to null)?

I have a class which might have a DateTime property value set or not. I was thinking of initializing the property holder to DateTime.MinValue, which then could easily be checked.

I've been searching a lot but couldn't find a solution.
I guess this is a quite common question, how do you do that?

Answer (score 503, accepted):

For normal DateTimes,  if you don't initialize them at all then they will match `DateTime.MinValue`, because it is a value type rather than a reference type.

You can also use a nullable DateTime, like this:

```
DateTime? MyNullableDate;
```

Or the longer form:

```
Nullable<DateTime> MyNullableDate;
```

And, finally, there's a built in way to reference the default of any type.  This returns `null` for reference types, but for our DateTime example it will return the same as `DateTime.MinValue`:

```
default(DateTime)
```

or, in more recent versions of C#,

```
default
```

Comment: It would greatly help if you provide an example of how to use it.  How do you assign the DateTime in the database, which could be DBNull, to the nullable DateTime?

Comment: It's also good to note that when you DO initialize them and with null, they are assigned `DateTime.MinValue` as well

Comment: @kirk.burleson that looks like a separate question.

Comment: you'll need `MyNullableDate=date;`  to set it, `MyDate = MyNullableDate.Value;` to read from it, and `if(MyNullableDate.HasValue)` to check if it is null

Comment: To clarify the answer's "finally" a bit - the default of Nullable<DateTime> (DateTime?) is null, because Nullable<T> creates a reference type.

Answer (score 98):

If you're using .NET 2.0 (or later) you can use the nullable type:

```
DateTime? dt = null;
```

or

```
Nullable<DateTime> dt = null;
```

then later:

```
dt = new DateTime();
```

And you can check the value with:

```
if (dt.HasValue)
{
  // Do something with dt.Value
}
```

Or you can use it like:

```
DateTime dt2 = dt ?? DateTime.MinValue;
```

You can read more here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx

Comment: You can use nullable types even in earlier versions of .NET, no need for 3.0.

Comment: It came in .NET 2.0 right? The ? syntax was added to VB.NET in 3.5, but it has been in C# since 2.0 I believe.

Comment: Nullable types are available in .Net 2.0. C# has had the shorthand ? notation from 2.0. Only VB.Net didn't have the shorthand ? in 2.0 but you could use Nullable(Of DateTime)

Comment: For the last snippet, I would say DateTime dt2 = dt ?? DateTime.MinValue;

Comment: I would use `dt.GetValueOrDefault()` -- it's the most efficient option.

Answer (score 45):

Following way works as well

```
myClass.PublishDate = toPublish ? DateTime.Now : (DateTime?)null;
```

Please note that property PublishDate should be DateTime?

Answer (score 41):

DateTime? MyDateTime{get;set;}

```
MyDateTime = (dr["f1"] == DBNull.Value) ? (DateTime?)null : ((DateTime)dr["f1"]);
```

Comment: This helped me discover passing just `null` doesn't work.  It needs to be `(DateTime?)null`.

Answer (score 14):

I'd consider using a [nullable types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(VS.80).aspx).

`DateTime? myDate` instead of `DateTime myDate`.

Answer (score 8):

You can set the DateTime to Nullable. By default DateTime is not nullable. You can make it nullable in a couple of ways. Using a question mark after the type DateTime? myTime or using the generic style Nullable.

```
DateTime? nullDate = null;
```

or

```
DateTime? nullDate;
```

Answer (score 8):

It is worth pointing out that, while a `DateTime` variable cannot be `null`, it still can be compared to `null` without a compiler error:

```
DateTime date;
...
if(date == null) // <-- will never be 'true'
  ...
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a nullable class.

```
DateTime? date = new DateTime?();
```

Comment: It's probably worth noting this will give you different behavior than instantiating a non-nullable `DateTime`.  As previously mentioned, `new DateTime()` will effectively give you `DateTime.Min` whereas `new DateTime?()` will result in null.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a nullable DateTime for this.

```
Nullable<DateTime> myDateTime;
```

or the same thing written like this:

```
DateTime? myDateTime;
```

Answer (score 5):

I always set the time to `DateTime.MinValue`. This way I do not get any NullErrorException and I can compare it to a date that I know isn't set.

Comment: That means you can't tell the difference between "I really need a DateTime here" and "It's optional" - Nullable<DateTime> is a much better solution, IMO.

Comment: ? I really do not get your comment. Yeah I know when the DateTime is so far aways of reality is like if it was null...

Comment: I am just suggesting an other solution. Instead of repeating what have been suggested already 10 times here.

Comment: I mean that your type system can't indicate the optional nature of the value.

Comment: It is convenient, but I view DateTime.MinValue as a value, not a special case condition.  It can only lead to problems down the line.  I'd go with Nullable<DateTime>.

Comment: Never got any problem since 2 years with this system.

Comment: There are any number of bad designs which won't always cause problems - but shouldn't be recommended anyway. I could come along and say that I make all members of all types public, and haven't had any problems - would that be good advice?

Comment: I think you miss something about my answer, Spoulson wrote something and I was answering. About public members, well it's not the same and you know it. it's like String.Empty or null. You can do both, not because String.Empty is better that null is wrong. What ever.

Comment: I'm with Daok on this. It might not be the "by the book" approach but it's better than getting a NullReferenceException or dealing with the cumbersome Nullable type. Besides, how many applications are out there that actually need to reference the date January 1, 1 A.D.?

Answer (score 4):

Just be warned - When using a Nullable its obviously no longer a 'pure' datetime object, as such you cannot access the DateTime members directly. I'll try and explain.

By using Nullable<> you're basically wrapping DateTime in a container (thank you generics) of which is nullable - obviously its purpose. This container has its own properties which you can call that will provide access to the aforementioned DateTime object; after using the correct property - in this case Nullable.Value - you then have access to the standard DateTime members, properties etc.

So - now the issue comes to mind as to the best way to access the DateTime object. There are a few ways, number 1 is by FAR the best and 2 is "dude why".

1. Using the Nullable.Value property,

   `DateTime date = myNullableObject.Value.ToUniversalTime(); //Works`

   `DateTime date = myNullableObject.ToUniversalTime(); //Not a datetime object, fails`
2. Converting the nullable object to datetime using Convert.ToDateTime(),

   `DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(myNullableObject).ToUniversalTime(); //works but why...`

Although the answer is well documented at this point, I believe the usage of Nullable was probably worth posting about. Sorry if you disagree.

edit: Removed a third option as it was a bit overly specific and case dependent.

Answer (score 2):

Although everyone has already given you the answer , I'll mention a way which makes it easy to pass a datetime into a function

**[ERROR:cannot convert system.datetime? to system.datetime]**

```
DateTime? dt = null;
DateTime dte = Convert.ToDateTime(dt);
```

Now you may pass dte inside the function without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you are, sometimes, expecting null you could use something like this:

```
var orderResults = Repository.GetOrders(id, (DateTime?)model.DateFrom, (DateTime?)model.DateTo)
```

In your repository use null-able datetime.

```
public Orders[] GetOrders(string id, DateTime? dateFrom, DateTime? dateTo){...}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as I had to give Null as a parameter for DateTime while performing Unit test for Throws ArgumentNullException.It worked in my case using the following option:

```
Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(()=>sut.StartingDate = DateTime.Parse(null));
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the nature of a date/time data type it cannot contain a `null` value, i.e. it needs to contain a value, it cannot be blank or contain nothing. If you mark a date/time variable as `nullable` then only can you assign a null value to it. So what you are looking to do is one of two things (there might be more but I can only think of two):

- Assign a minimum date/time value to your variable if you don't have a value for it. You can assign a maximum date/time value as well - whichever way suits you. Just make sure that you are consistent site-wide when checking your date/time values. Decide on using `min` or `max` and stick with it.
- Mark your date/time variable as `nullable`. This way you can set your date/time variable to `null` if you don't have a variable to it.

Let me demonstrate my first point using an example. The `DateTime` variable type cannot be set to null, it needs a value, in this case I am going to set it to the `DateTime`'s minimum value if there is no value.

My scenario is that I have a `BlogPost` class. It has many different fields/properties but I chose only to use two for this example. `DatePublished` is when the post was published to the website and has to contain a date/time value. `DateModified` is when a post is modified, so it doesn't have to contain a value, but can contain a value.

```
public class BlogPost : Entity
{
     public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }

     public DateTime DatePublished { get; set; }
}
```

Using `ADO.NET` to get the data from the database (assign `DateTime.MinValue` is there is no value):

```
BlogPost blogPost = new BlogPost();
blogPost.DateModified = sqlDataReader.IsDBNull(0) ? DateTime.MinValue : sqlDataReader.GetFieldValue<DateTime>(0);
blogPost.DatePublished = sqlDataReader.GetFieldValue<DateTime>(1);
```

You can accomplish my second point by marking the `DateModified` field as `nullable`. Now you can set it to `null` if there is no value for it:

```
public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
```

Using `ADO.NET` to get the data from the database, it will look a bit different to the way it was done above (assigning `null` instead of `DateTime.MinValue`):

```
BlogPost blogPost = new BlogPost();
blogPost.DateModified = sqlDataReader.IsDBNull(0) ? (DateTime?)null : sqlDataReader.GetFieldValue<DateTime>(0);
blogPost.DatePublished = sqlDataReader.GetFieldValue<DateTime>(1);
```

I hope this helps to clear up any confusion. Given that my response is about 8 years later you are probably an expert C# programmer by now :)

Answer (score 0):

The question itself answers it the proper way. "How do you deal with datetime if it is null?" and questioner gives the answer at the end with DateTime.MinValue. My thought is that questioner's approach should be the way with little change. I would recommend using DateTime.MaxValue to compare since it wont happen until 12/31/9999. If true then show field as something else other than a date. Here is the example;

```
 DateNotified = DBNull.Value.Equals(reader["DateNotified"])? Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DateNotified"]): DateTime.MaxValue
```

and on the front end
if it is Grid you are using then;

```
columns.Add(col => col.DateNotified).Css("text-right").Titled("Date Notified").RenderValueAs(c => c.DateNotified.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy").Equals(DateTime.MaxValue) ? "":c.DateNotified.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

or if a simple view then

```
@Model.DateNotified.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy").Equals(DateTime.MaxValue) ? "":Model.DateNotified.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```