# Can a DateTime be null?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, object, null

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DateTime “null” value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221732/datetime-null-value)

is it possible to set datetime object to null?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`DateTime` is a [value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx), which, just like `int` and `double`, has no meaningful `null` value.

In VB.NET, you can write this:

```
Dim d As DateTime = Nothing
```

But all this does is to set `d` to the *default* `DateTime` value. In C# the equivalent code would be this:

```
DateTime d = default(DateTime);
```

...which is equivalent to `DateTime.MinValue`.

That said, there is the [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) type, which is used to provide a `null` value for any value type `T`. The shorthand for `Nullable<DateTime>` in C# is `DateTime?`.

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime? myDate = null;
```

The question mark will give you a nullable type. The one that can either be set to its native value or to null.

`DateTime` itself is a value type. It cannot be null.

Answer (score 4):

Nope, you cannot for `DateTime` is a value type.

You might want to look at [`Nullable<DateTime>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) though (or DateTime? in short)

Answer (score 4):

No -- DateTime is a struct in C# and structs (value types) can not be null.

You can, however, use `Nullable<DateTime>.`

Answer (score 2):

No, its a structure not a class. Either make it a nullable type, e.g. System.DateTime? myValue; or use the System.DateTime.MinValue as a sentinel.

Comment: Be careful with your wording. Nullable<T> is a structure too and can contain a null.

Answer (score 2):

Normally DateTime cannot be null, since is a Value Type, but using the nullable operator introduced in C# 2, you can accomplish this