# C# Dynamic Linq Ternary Operator

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause, expression-trees, dynamic-linq

I want to make a dynamic check for a null value.
I want to make a where clause which will compare only the date part of the date field.

It will work for non nullable date fields, but for nullable date fields we need to check for value as using .Date on null data will throw an error

let us say

```
p => (p.Date.Value == null ? null : p.Date.Value.Date) == SelectedDate.Date
```

or

```
 p => ( p.Date.Value == null ? p.Date.Value : p.Date.Value.Date) == SelectedDate.Date
```

or

```
p => (p.Date.Value == null ? p.Date : p.Date.Value.Date) == SelectedDate.Date
```

basically a null checking ternary operator which selects only the date part of

I already tried

```
ConstantExpression argument = Expression.Constant(MyDateField, typeof(DateTime));
ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
string field = "Date";
BinaryExpression condition = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameter, field), Expression.Constant(null, typeof(DateTime?)));
ConditionalExpression ternary = Expression.Condition(condition, property, Expression.Property(property, "Date"));
Expression equalExp = Expression.Equal(ternary, argument);
lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(equalExp, parameter);
```

Which gives me

```
p => (IIF((p.EventDate == null), p.EventDate.Value, p.EventDate.Value.Date) == 21-Jun-18 12:00:00 AM)
```

but this is not working.
Issue I'm facing is

If I use p.Date.Value in the BinaryExpression then it doesnot allow as .Value makes it DateTime and null is only available in DateTime?

`IIF` condition is generated and not `?:` ternary operator

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: DateTime null ? read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635678/can-a-datetime-be-null

Comment: @Amit The type here is **DateTime?** or **Nullable<DateTime>**

Comment: @SirRufo yes that too is there in that question. i may have out look that here OP is using DateTime? .. let me re read it

Comment: @Amit Second paragraph: *but for **nullable** date fields we need to check*

Comment: @SirRufo yeah i have seen that now. mybad

Comment: What about just: `p => p.Date.GetValueOrDefault().Date == SelectedDate.Date`

Comment: `p.Date.Value == null ? null : p.Date.Value.Date` this is already wrong. `p.Date == null ? (DateTime?)null : (DateTime?)p.Date.Value.Date`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DateTime?` and `DateTime` are different types. While the C# compiler does some implicit conversions sometimes (for example when you compare them with `==`), with Lambda Expressions you have to make explicit casts. And to get the value of a `DateTime?` you have to use the `.Value` property.

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> MakeExpression<T>(DateTime myDateField)
{
    ConstantExpression argument = Expression.Constant(myDateField, typeof(DateTime));
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");

    string propertyName = "Date";
    Expression property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);

    BinaryExpression condition = Expression.Equal(property, Expression.Constant(null, typeof(DateTime?)));
    Expression propertyValue = Expression.Property(property, nameof(Nullable<DateTime>.Value));
    Expression propertyValueDate = Expression.Property(propertyValue, nameof(DateTime.Date));
    ConditionalExpression ternary = Expression.Condition(condition, Expression.Constant(null, typeof(DateTime?)), Expression.Convert(propertyValueDate, typeof(DateTime?)));
    Expression argumentDate = Expression.Property(argument, nameof(DateTime.Date));
    Expression equalExp = Expression.Equal(ternary, Expression.Convert(argumentDate, typeof(DateTime?)));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(equalExp, parameter);
    return lambda;
}
```

Note that `Nullable<>` defines a `HasValue` property, instead of comparing the value with `null`... So you could:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> MakeExpression<T>(DateTime myDateField)
{
    ConstantExpression argument = Expression.Constant(myDateField, typeof(DateTime));
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");

    string propertyName = "Date";
    Expression property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);

    Expression propertyHasvalue = Expression.Property(property, nameof(Nullable<DateTime>.HasValue));
    Expression propertyValue = Expression.Property(property, nameof(Nullable<DateTime>.Value));
    Expression propertyValueDate = Expression.Property(propertyValue, nameof(DateTime.Date));
    ConditionalExpression ternary = Expression.Condition(Expression.Not(propertyHasvalue), Expression.Constant(null, typeof(DateTime?)), Expression.Convert(propertyValueDate, typeof(DateTime?)));
    Expression argumentDate = Expression.Property(argument, nameof(DateTime.Date));
    Expression equalExp = Expression.Equal(ternary, Expression.Convert(argumentDate, typeof(DateTime?)));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(equalExp, parameter);
    return lambda;
}
```

Comment: the expression being made is correct, but I am getting the error "The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported." the field on which I'm trying to filter is nullable.

Comment: @DevanshiParikh Entity Framework probably doesn't support the `DateTime.Date`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9642274/613130 for possible solutions. `DbFunctions` for EF6.0, `EF.Functions` for EF Core

Answer (score 3):

Let say we have two expressions `left` and `right`, where the `right` type is `DateTime`, and we want to compare them for equality.

When the `left` type is `DateTime`, the comparison is simply

```
left == right
```

and when the `left` type is `DateTime?`, then

```
(left == (DateTime?)null ? (DateTime?)null : (DateTime?)left.Value.Date) == (DateTime?)right
```

I specifically added the required casts. C# compiler does some of them implicitly (like `(DateTime?)null`), but the important is that the ternary operator result type should be `DateTime?`, hence both ternary operator operands type **and** equality operator operands type must be `DateTime?` as well.

With that being said, let translate the aforementioned rules to code:

```
static Expression<Func<T, bool>> DateEquals<T>(string memberName, DateTime value)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
    Expression left = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, memberName);
    Expression right = Expression.Constant(value.Date);
    if (left.Type == typeof(DateTime?))
    {
        var leftValue = Expression.Property(left, "Value");
        var nullValue = Expression.Constant(null, typeof(DateTime?));
        left = Expression.Condition(
            Expression.Equal(left, nullValue),
            nullValue,
            Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(leftValue, "Date"), typeof(DateTime?))
        );
        right = Expression.Convert(right, typeof(DateTime?));
    }
    var condition = Expression.Equal(left, right);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(condition, parameter);
}
```

(Don't worry that you see `IIF` in the debug display. The `Conditional` expression shown as `IIF` is indeed the expression equivalent of the C# `? :` operator)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your `p.Date` is `DateTime?` (or `Nullable<DateTime>`)

```
p => p.Date?.Date == SelectedDate.Date
```

Comment: `?.` is not supported in expression trees.

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working is

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> MakeExpression<T>(DateTime myDateField, string fieldName)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
        var property = Expression.Property(parameter, fieldName);
        var fieldType = property.Type;
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> lambda = null;

        if (fieldType == typeof(DateTime?))
        {
            var truncateTimeMethod = typeof(DbFunctions).GetMethod("TruncateTime", new[] { fieldType });
            if (truncateTimeMethod != null)
            {
                var propertyHasvalue = Expression.Property(property, nameof(Nullable<DateTime>.HasValue));
                var truncateTimeMethodCall = Expression.Call(truncateTimeMethod, property);
                var ternary = Expression.Condition(Expression.Not(propertyHasvalue), property, truncateTimeMethodCall);
                var argument = Expression.Constant(myDateField.Date, typeof(DateTime?));
                var equalExp = Expression.Equal(ternary, argument);

                lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(equalExp, parameter);
            }
        }
        return lambda;
    }
```

Thanks to @xanatos

For the .Date functionality

```
var truncateTimeMethod = typeof(DbFunctions).GetMethod("TruncateTime", new[] { fieldType });
var truncateTimeMethodCall = Expression.Call(truncateTimeMethod, property);
```

For Ternary Operation

```
var ternary = Expression.Condition(Expression.Not(propertyHasvalue), property, truncateTimeMethodCall);
```