# How to pass the null value to datetime datatype in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

How to pass the null value to datetime datatype in asp.net?

```
cmdInsertUpdateConsultantDetails.Parameters.Add("@DateofExpiry", SqlDbType.DateTime);
if (txtdateofexpiry.Text.Trim() == "")
{
    cmdInsertUpdateConsultantDetails.Parameters["@DateofExpiry"].Value =
}
else
{
    cmdInsertUpdateConsultantDetails.Parameters["@DateofExpiry"].Value = 
        Convert.ToDateTime(txtdateofexpiry.Text.Trim());
}
```

Comment: add "?". DateTime ? currentDateTime;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple here you can give `DbNull.Value` to pass `NULL` value.

```
if (txtdateofexpiry.Text.Trim() == "")
{
    cmdInsertUpdateConsultantDetails.Parameters["@DateofExpiry"].Value = DbNull.Value
}
```

It's also recommended the use of `DateTime?` or [Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

DateTime is a value type, it cannot be null. You can use `Nullable<DateTime>` (or the syntax shortform `DateTime?`) instead of that.

Here's an example:

```
DateTime? dateTime;
DateTime.TryParseExact(txtdateofexpiry.Text.Trim(), "dd/MM/yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime);
```

Comment: datetimeStyle.None is the error any namespaces are added pls give me some idea

Comment: DateTimeStyles enum is in System.Globalization namespace if that's what you are asking. You should also check [DateTime formats here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

Answer (score 3):

DateTime is not a nullable type. If you don't supply a value it's equal to DateTime.MinValue

You can use

```
DateTime? MyNullableDateTime;
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221732/datetime-null-value) has more detail in the answer, if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass it as `DBNull.Value`. So it would be

```
cmdInsertUpdateConsultantDetails.Parameters.Add("@DateofExpiry", SqlDbType.DateTime);
if (txtdateofexpiry.Text.Trim() == "")
{
    cmdInsertUpdateConsultantDetails.Parameters["@DateofExpiry"].Value = DBNull.Value;
}
else
{
    cmdInsertUpdateConsultantDetails.Parameters["@DateofExpiry"].Value = 
          Convert.ToDateTime(txtdateofexpiry.Text.Trim());
}
```