# How to handle passing DBNull into a function?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, vb.net

I'm returning results from a stored procedure and passing them off to a function for further processing.  In some cases, it's possible (and perfectly fine) for one of the fields, a date value, to return null.

However, whenever I pass the null into the function, an exception is thrown trying to convert the null into there function parameter's type.  What is the best way to handle this?

Data:

```
Name    StartDate    EndDate
Bob     01/01/2013   NULL
```

Calling Function:

```
MyFunction(
           DataRow.Item("StartDate"), 
           DataRow.Item("EndDate")) ' <--- invalid cast exception
```

Function:

```
Public Function MyFunction(
                           ByVal StartDate as Date, 
                           ByVal EndDate as Date) As Object
    ....
    Return something
End Function
```

**EDIT:** Lots of great tips but still no dice.

Declaring the DateTime type in the function as nullable, `ByVal EndDate as DateTime?`, results in `System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.`

Using DataRow.Field(Of DateTime)("EndDate") along with declaring the parameter as a nullable type results in `System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.DateTime'`

**EDIT2:** Found a source of one of my problems.  I was using Iif(), and one of the values was of type System.DBNull, the other was of type Date.  And both the true and false parts must be the same type.  Took me a while to spot that.

Comment: I don't think Date is nullable types..

Comment: Bear this in mind in the future too, many datatypes aren't nullable by default, and have to be explicitly declared as such for a null value to be allowable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try can making the parameter [`Nullable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2):

```
Public Function MyFunction(ByVal StartDate as DateTime, ByVal EndDate as DateTime?) As Object
    ....
    Return something
End Function
```

But you might need to call it using the the [`Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.field.aspx) method:

```
MyFunction(DataRow.Field(Of DateTime)("StartDate"), DataRow.Field(Of DateTime?)("EndDate"))
```

Comment: I never knew about the `?` shorthand for Nullable!  What a great, unexpected tip.

Comment: If I use your Field(Of DateTime) suggestion, I get "System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.DateTime'. Please use a nullable type." ... if I use just row.Item("..") then I get "System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid."  Any thoughts?

Comment: @user1003916 Note that it's `Field(Of DateTime?)` (nullable, with a `?`). This should work. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.aspx): "*If the value of the specified DataColumn is Value and *T* is a reference type or nullable type, the return type will be **null**. The Field method will not return DBNull.Value.*". If `StartDate` can be nullable too, you might need to use `Field(Of DateTime?)` with both arguments.

Answer (score 6):

Use a [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) DateTime parameter:

```
 ByVal EndDate AS Nullable(Of DateTime)
```

Full example:

```
Public Function MyFunction(ByVal StartDate as Date, ByVal EndDate as Nullable(Of DateTime)) As Object
    ....
    Return something
End Function
```

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that DateTime was functionally any different from Date.  I always wondered about that.  Thank you.

Comment: @Darren Davies I tried that and now it's giving me a more generic error on the same line.. "System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid."

Answer (score 0):

you should look into using a nullable value for the values that can be null.  Take a look here for an example.... [DateTime "null" value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221732/datetime-null-value)

Comment: Not sure if start time should be nullable too, but something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

From the database side you can null check the date time and assign any date something like '1/1/1990'

Comment: This sounds like a terrible idea.