# Empty data converts to {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}

Tags: json, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have model with `id` and `date`. Then I make it `angular.toJson` and send to server. The problem is in that: if my date is empty, model's date field on server shows as {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM} but not null. How to solve this? I need `null`.

Here is angularjs controller where my function calls

```
$scope.filterModel = function (filter) {
    postService.getFilteredByUserId($scope.bindModel, angular.toJson(filter));
};
```

Here is my server function that gets this model

```
[HttpPost]
public IEnumerable<TimesheetModel> FilterModel(TimesheetFilterModel filter)
{
    return TimesheetService.FilterTimesheetListByFilter(filter);
}
```

Here is model:

```
public class TimesheetFilterModel
{
    public int      UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }
    public int      TicketType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You should use `nullable<DateTime` - public DateTime? DateFrom { get; set; }. You can check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221732/datetime-null-value)

Comment: Yeah, sure. My miss... Thanks!)

Answer (score 3):

```
public class TimesheetFilterModel
{
    public int      UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateTo { get; set; }
    public int      TicketType { get; set; }

    public TimesheetFilterModel() {
        DateFrom = null;
        DateTo = null;
    }
}
```

by default, DateTime is not nullable. You need to make them nullable and set them to null on Constructor.

Comment: You do not need to set `null` in a constructor (the default is `null`)

Answer (score 1):

You can make the datetime property nullable so that on getting null value it will handle the null.

DateTime is a value type in c# so assigning null value in it not possible directly.

```
DateTime? nullableDate;
dateSample.Value = null;
```

In your case it's going to default to `DateTime.MinValue`.

Comment: You do not need to set null in a constructor (the default is null)