# How to set datetime value as null in ultrawingrid

Tags: c#

view to bind data from Data-source and displaying the data in ultrawingrid when the date field is having System.DateTime.MaxValue I need to set a null or empty value in it. I was unable to set it.

Comment: Why were you unable to set it? What happened, what is your code at all?

Comment: When I am setting it to null its showing an error saying that DateTime fields does not allow null values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DateTime "null" value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221732/datetime-null-value)

Answer (score 1):

You can't set DateTime to null. It's value type but not reference type. Like structures, int, double, etc.
You can use `Nullable<DateTime>` (the same = `DateTime?` ).
Or instantiate it with default value `var someDateTime = default(DateTime);`

Comment: But when setting to default its showing System.DateTime.min value

Comment: Only reference type variable could be equal to null. All value-type variables could have only some value like nubmers, dates and so on.  Null is not a value, it's like a flag, that referenced value does not specify any reference to value, that's why null could not be applyed to value-type variables.

Comment: Use `Nullable<SomeValueType>`  (short syntax it `SomeValueType?` )

Comment: Is there any solution to do display null value ?? either by changing the data type ??