# LINQ, MySQL: null dates in WHERE clause?

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I am new to LINQ.  I am trying to convert an existing MySQL query.  I have a table of events and a table that builds "session" records.

The event table has many, mostly `varchar`, columns and at least one `datetime` column.

The session table has a `startId` field that is a link back to the primary key of the event table and specifies the event that started the session.  There is an `endId` field that will either be `NULL` (session is active) or be a pointer into the event table to the record that ended the session.

I want to search for sessions that were active on a certain date.  in MySQL I can say:

```
select
    *
from
    Sessions s
    inner join EventLogs eStart on s.StartId equals eStart.Id
    inner join EventLogs eEnd on s.EndId equals eEnd.Id
where
    '<some date string>' betwen eStart.Date and ifnull(eEnd.Date, now())
```

I have not seen that LINQ has a `between` operator so I do the next best thing.  What is getting me at this instant is that I am not sure how to express the `ifnull(eEnd.Date, now())` in LINQ.  I am currently trying:

```
var result = 
    from s in dbContext.Sessions
    join eStart in dbContext.EventLogs on s.StartId equals eStart.Id
    join eEnd in dbContext.EventLogs on s.EndId equals eEnd.Id
    where ('<some date string>' >= eStart.Date) 
        && ('<some date string>' <= (eEnd.Date ?? DateTime.Today))
```

But I am told that the `??` operator can not be applied to operands of type DateTime.  What is the magic here?

Comment: You could use ?? if your DateTime is declared as nullable (DateTime?).

Comment: You make make the DateTime nullable if you need to accommodate null values in the database.

`DateTime? startdate`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221732/datetime-null-value