# Blank value need in DatePicker

Tags: xamarin.forms, datepicker, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Currently working on a Xamarin.Forms app where we need a blank value in       `DatePicker` when the user did not select any date or when the form is loaded for the first time.

Here

```
DatePicker DO = new DatePicker();
DO.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy";

DO.Date = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/1900");
```

we got this `01/01/1900` when the user did not select a date. But not the null or blank value in `DatePicker` field.

[image: Not null value]

Answer (score -5):

Check below link it will be help you.Otherwise instead of DateTime collection take collection of String.

```
List<DateTimeString> dateCollection=new List<DateTimeString>();
dateCollection.add("")-- if required check null values and add.
```

https://www.dotnetperls.com/nullable-datetime

[DateTime "null" value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221732/datetime-null-value)

Comment: Xamarin datepicker by default can't use a nullable datetime object.  So TylerH will get a null reference exception if he makes the binding nullable.

Comment: First link is broken. Second link only shows how to get a null date in C# code, not in a Xamarin Form date picker control.