# DateTime calculator

Tags: c#

I am trying to set int? to `null` or to the dateTime.Year or a TimeSpan. I am checking if the dt is equal to the default datetime. Then setting the int? to null or a calculated value. Is this the correct way to do this?

```
DateTime? dtnull = null;
DateTime? dt = new DateTime(2023, 09,27,00,00,00);
DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;

int? RemainingDaysnull = (dtnull == default(DateTime)) ? null : (dtnull.Value - currentDateTime).Days;
int? Last4EndDatenull = (dtnull == default(DateTime)) ? null(dtnull.Value).Year;
int? RemainingDays = (dt == default(DateTime)) ? null : (dt - currentDateTime).Days;
int? Last4EndDate = (dt == default(DateTime)) ? null : (dt.Value).Year();
```

Comment: `dtnull` is never `default(DateTime)` because the former is null and the latter is 0001-01-01. Also `null(dtNullValue).Year` doesn’t compile.

Comment: `default(DateTime)` returns `DateTime.MinValue` not `null`

Comment: Since code does not even compile... why do you believe this is "the correct way" ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DateTime "null" value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221732/datetime-null-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler that the expression should evaluate as an int?. Try either of these:

Instead try

```
 int? RemainingDaysnull = (dtnull == default(DateTime)) ? (int?)null : (dtnull.Value - currentDateTime).Days;
```

Or

```
 int? RemainingDaysnull = (dtnull == default(DateTime)) ? null : (int?)(dtnull.Value - currentDateTime).Days;
```

Comment: You can if the value in the other part of the conditional is a nullable type.  For instance you could apply the `(int?)` to the other side and it will work.

Comment: I created this sample https://dotnetfiddle.net/6BXVWw where I am getting the error

Comment: Within your dotnetfiddle you're initialising dt (line 8) with NULL, then in your comparison on line 11 your firstly checking if it's equal to default(DateTime) which it isn't so it then tries to get the value of (dt dt.value) this is where it will be falling over. Unless dt is being populated with a valid value I can't see what you're trying to achieve with this block of code.

Comment: Change line 8 in your dotnetfiddle to something like - `DateTime? dt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);`

Comment: @GraemeC The code would need to both in both case if dt has a value or is null. Why when I set to to `Now.AddDays(7)` it works?

Comment: should it be `int? RemainingDays = (dt == null) ? null : (int?)(dt.Value - currentDateTime).Days;`

Comment: I'd say the safest way would be to set it to `int? RemainingDays = (dt.GetValueOrDefault() == DateTime.MinValue) ? null : (int?)(dt.Value - currentDateTime).Days;` this way on your first comparison the `dt.GetValueOrDefault()` is saying get the value of dt or if this null get the default value of DateTime which is DateTime.MinValue

Answer (score 2):

It's not really clear what you are trying to achieve, but here is how you could get check that `dt`
is well populated and then calculate a couple of values when that's true.

```
int? remainingDays = null;
int? last4EndDate = null;

if (dt.HasValue && dt.Value > DateTime.MinValue)
{
    remainingDays = (dt.Value - currentDateTime).Days;
    last4EndDate = dt.Value.Year;
}
```

Comment: You could do `if(dt > DateTime.MinValu)` as a comparison involving a `null` `DateTime?` with a `DateTime` will be false

Comment: @juharr Yea, I know.  I'm just trying to keep it baby steps because the requirements aren't exactly clear.

Comment: @juharr why do I need to set  `remainingDays = null` to null?

Comment: @Jefferson Null is just a default value, incase your `if` statement is false.  It doesn't have to be null; you can set it to whatever value you need.